# rails 7 zietwerk constants not found

Tags: ruby, autoload, ruby-on-rails-7, zeitwerk

I'm upgrading our app from rails 6 to 7, I was using zeitwerk instead of the classic autoloader with rails 6 without any issues, now without any changes to the folder/file naming convention or structure it fails to find any classes/modules inside lib folder. I've been debugging the zeitwerk gem and the autoloads hash has file paths as keys and `[Namespace, Constant Name]` as the value, with rails 6 it had correct name space, e.g. for a file in `\user\project\rails6_test\lib\folder\config.rb` it'd have `Folder` as the namespace and `Config` defined inside `config.rb` would be found correctly in `Folder` namespace but after the migration with rails 7 it always has `Object` as the namespace, not just for top level folders but for all nested files and obviously it can't find those constants in the `Object`.

I don't see anything that I missed from the upgrade guide, what could be missing here ?

***Update***

I tried running `bin/rails r 'pp ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` and I get the error below,

```
/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:25:in `on_file_autoloaded': expected file /home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/restful_resource.rb to define constant RestfulResource, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)

  raise Zeitwerk::NameError.new("expected file #{file} to define constant #{cpath}, but didn't", cref.last)
  ^^^^^
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:28:in `require'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:95:in `const_get'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:95:in `cget'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:238:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:26:in `block in ls'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:18:in `each_child'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:18:in `ls'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:233:in `block in eager_load'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:218:in `synchronize'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:218:in `eager_load'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:318:in `each'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:318:in `eager_load_all'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:78:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
    from /home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/rainman/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:348:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:28:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/runner/runner_command.rb:33:in `perform'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have `config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib"` in my application.rb and to test eager loading with zeitwerk I add `config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`, let me know if you need any more info.

***Update 2***

After getting rid of the wildcard with just `/lib` running `bin/rails r 'pp ActiveSupport::Dependencies.eager_load_paths'` gives me the following output

```
["/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/microservices/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/microservices/dir/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/dir/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/dir/dir/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/dir/dir/dir/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/dir/dir/dir/dir/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/dir/dir/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/dir/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/dir/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/dir/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/tasks/",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/app/controllers",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/app/mailers",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/app/models",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/app/serializers",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/app/workers",
 "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.2.2/app/controllers",
 "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.2.2/app/jobs",
 "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.2.2/app/models",
 "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.2.2/app/controllers",
 "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.2.2/app/controllers/concerns",
 "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.2.2/app/jobs",
 "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.2.2/app/models",
 "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/spec/mailers/previews"]
```

and running `bin/rails r 'pp ActiveSupport::Dependencies._eager_load_paths'` outputs the following

```
{"/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.2.2/app/controllers",
  "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.2.2/app/controllers/concerns",
  "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.2.2/app/jobs",
  "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.2.2/app/models",
  "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.2.2/app/controllers",
  "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.2.2/app/jobs",
  "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.2.2/app/models",
  "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actiontext-7.0.2.2/app/helpers",
  "/home/leonidas/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actiontext-7.0.2.2/app/models",
  "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/app/controllers",
  "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/app/mailers",
  "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/app/models",
  "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/app/serializers",
  "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/app/workers",
  "/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib"}
```

I was looking into the `zeitwerk.rake` task in rails and it seems it doesn't check any existing and non empty directories that exist in autoload paths but not in the eager load paths, I don't understand what should be happening here, is `autoload_paths` not supposed to have the expanded folder structure and only list root folders ? because in my case autoload having nested dirs too and eager_load only having root dirs is printing that warning about not checking the folders inside lib.

Comment: Does `/home/leonidas/projects/ruby_on_rails/project_name/lib/project_name/restful_resource.rb` define `RestfulResource`?

Comment: yeah, it defines `module ProjectName;  class RestfulResource; end; end`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the updates. The problem is this glob:

```rb
config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Adding to the eager load paths, adds also to the autoload paths (I find this a bit confusing, but it is how it works). Therefore, that glob is adding, for example, `lib/project_name` to the autoload paths. The key observation to understand what is happening is that when there are nested root paths, [the most nested one wins](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#nested-root-directories) as far as the files and directories below that one is concerned.

So, since `lib` is in the autoload paths, anything below `lib` is assumed to be defined in `Object`. But, since `lib/project_name` is in the autoload paths too, that subtree also represents `Object`. It is the same situation like the one you have in `app/models` and `app/models/concerns`.

[These docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#globs-in-config-autoload-paths) explain it, but they were easy to overlook in this case because it was not obvious your configuration is affected by that point.

The solution is to add only `lib`:

```rb
config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib"
config.eager_load_paths << "#{config.root}/lib"
```

Just like that, without wildcards. Technically, the first line is redundant given the second one, but in my view this is subtle and not obvious, I personally like to make both explicit, but as you like here. (There won't be duplicated entries, the final collection passes through `uniq`.)

Since we are on it, let me also comment something extra. Maybe your application already does this, but just in case, let me say that `lib` has often files and directories that are not meant to be autoloaded. For example, `lib/tasks`. It is clean to be deliberate about them and tell the autoloader:

```rb
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore("#{config.root}/lib/tasks")
```

Otherwise, the autoloader will believe `lib/tasks` is a namespace, will define an autoload for `Tasks` in `Object`, will eager load (== actually define) the module if eager loading is enabled, etc. Conceptually, `lib/tasks` does not have code to be autoloaded/eager loaded, and the configuration has to reflect that. Same with other similar directories.

Comment: Hi @XavierNoria, yeah I started with `config.eager_load_paths << "#{config.root}/lib"` first because that's how I tested and set it up with rails 6 but now with rails 7 having that in `application.rb` and running the check gives me a warning saying the directories inside `lib/project_name` will only be checked if I configure them to be eager loaded and it lists all the nested directories inside the lib folder

Comment: That is strange. I just checked and cannot reproduce. That would happen if the configuration pushes `lib` to the autoload paths and **not** to the eager load paths. And it would say so only for `lib`, not for nested directories. If the app does what my answer above says, `zeitwerk:check` reports a missing directory in the eager load paths?

Comment: I've put some more info with the difference in autoload and eager load paths after doing some debugging in the zeitwerk rake task as Update 2, can you see something wrong there ?

Comment: Definitely, the autoload paths are suspicious. All those inner directories shouldn't be there, just `lib`. I cannot imagine a way of having them there other than a manual configuration that we are overlooking in the application (assuming no weird external things like side-effects of Spring or Docker containers). Could you do a search for "*" within `config`?

Comment: found it, turns out I had accidentally left the auto load paths with wildcards in development.rb, which I had put in while trying to figure out the initial issue of everything inheriting from Object, anyway thanks for all you help in debugging the issue, +1 to Zeitwerk.

Comment: Awesome, we found it .

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error with Zeitwerk and the solution was to revise my class name, as I had something like "`SomeImportantClassNameWithID`"

And the mistake was that I had "ID" at the end of it, but it should have been "Id" - to make a proper CamelCase that matches the snake_case name of the file, to be loaded correctly by Zeitwerk.

i.e. `SomeImportantClassNameWithID` was wrong
and `SomeImportantClassNameWithId` fixed it

Conclusion:
Zeitwerk is case sensitive so double check your class names.