# Zeitwerk and extentions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, zeitwerk

I'm having some troubles with Zeitwerk when migrating to Rails 7.

I got:

```
# config/initializers/monkey_patches.rb:4
Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'extensions', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

String.include Extensions::String
Devise::FailureApp.send :prepend, Extensions::Devise::FailureAppCustom
```

`Extensions::Devise::FailureAppCustom` is defined undes `lib/extensions/devise/failure_app_custom.rb`

and I got `NameError Exception: uninitialized constant Extensions::Devise`

I thought it was because the module `Extensions` was not created so I've added it before

```
module Extensions; end
```

Still not working.

I made tons of update having different errors like

`uninitialized constant Devise::FailureApp`

I also have `config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb`

where I'm defining

```
# Fixing loading issue
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/71574682/2616474
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(Rails.root.join("app/middleware"))

ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << 'app/deliveries/concerns'
```

```rb
# lib/extensions/devise/failure_app_custom.rb

module Extensions
  module Devise
    module FailureAppCustom

      protected

      def warden_message
        # Original checks `warden.message` first
        # We need to be able to force message without rewriting
        # the winning stragery of warden (Devise::Strategies::DatabaseAuthenticatable)
        @message ||= warden_options[:message] || warden.message
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I've read [this point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71366523) from @XavierNoria but I'm not able to fully understand how this should be declare properly.

Comment: That is unrelated to Zeitwerk. The code is doing `require` calls in a directory I presume is not managed by the main loader. Also, during initialization in Rails 7 the main loader is not even ready to load anything. With the given information, this seems like a regular Ruby issue. Please note that Extensions is found, what it is not found is Extensions::Devise. Maybe you could share some content of that file?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @XavierNoria
Actually what I don't understand is that I only have this issue when deploying on puma restart. Locally I never have it. Neither in the CI. That's why I thought it was a Zeitwerk configuration issue somehow. 
I've added the content of the `FailureAppCustom`

Comment: This was a stupid error. I don't even know it was able to work before. `Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'extensions', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }` only the first level files were required.. 
Sorry about that @XavierNoria

Answer (score 0):

Basic issue.

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'extensions','**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

Only the first level of files were required. Just needed to add all of them below (`**`)